# What is the appropriate way to authorize a subset of a collection provided by a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a controller, `foo`, that handles a GET request to `foo/bars` by responding with a collection of `bar` objects. I would like my custom `AuthorizationHandler` and controller to work together to ensure that when a user that has permission to see bars with an ID of 1, 2 and 3 but not 4, 5, and 6 the controller returns the correct subset of `bar` objects.

This is a dotnet core 2.2 webApi. The request will have an access token in the `Authorization` header as a Bearer token. The access token will have appropriate claims to make the decision. What is the best way to use the Authorization process to create the filter the controller must apply when retrieving the list of `bar`s from the data source?

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that should be done via authorization, as you're filtering a set of entities. Authorization is for deciding whether the user can access *anything*. What you need to do is add a property to the entities to track who "owns" it, there could be potentially many "owners" if that's a requirement. Then, when you do your query, you simply add in the current user to the query to select only those items where that users is the or one of the owners. For example, let's say you persisted something like `OwnerId` on the entities, then you would do:

```
var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
var foos = await _context.Foos.Where(x => x.OwnerId == userId).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field in your POCO like bool IsAdmin which you can get or set. 
At set time, you can set it to those people who have access.

Then you can check:

```
var foos = await _context.Foos.Where(x => x.IsAdmin).ToListAsync();
```